# Findout pagesize programmatically

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, paging

In Linux, how can we know the page size of a process i.e the size of a page which

have been allocated to the process, programmatically using Loadable Kernel Module

Comment: The question isn't clear enough; do you ask for userspace or kernelspace solution? In either case loadable kernel modules seam completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

For code running in the kernel: the macro `PAGE_SIZE` I think it what you want.

If running a process in userspace, you can call `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` to get the page size.